# org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AbstractAggregationBuilder not found during compilation

Tags: java, elasticsearch, gradle, spring-data-elasticsearch

I get this error while compiling a Spring Boot application on 19.0.2 using spring-data-elasticsearch with the recent dependencies.

org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AbstractAggregationBuilder not found during compilation

```
./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.0.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-03-03 16:41:37 UTC
Revision:     7d6581558e226a580d91d399f7dfb9e3095c2b1d

Kotlin:       1.8.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          19.0.2 (Private Build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04)
OS:           Linux 5.19.0-38-generic amd64

java --version
openjdk 19.0.2 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04, mixed mode, sharing)

> Task :compileJava FAILED
An exception has occurred in the compiler (19.0.2). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program, the following diagnostic, and the parameters passed to the Java compiler in your report. Thank you.
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AbstractAggregationBuilder not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AbstractAggregationBuilder` was coming from the old Elasticsearch client libraries in version 7.17 and used with the `NativeQueryBuilder` and the Elasticsearch `RestHighLevelClient`.

For the new Elasticsearch client used in Spring Data Elasticsearch version 5.0 you will need to use the client classes from the elasticsearch-java client library like `co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.aggregations.Aggregation`.